# Visual Studio Code sh: 0: Can't open undefined/build.sh

Tags: c#, ubuntu, settings, visual-studio-code

Recently I performed a clean install of Kubuntu 15.10 on my laptop and installed Visual Studio Code in order to code C#, F# and other Microsoft based languages.

Using the internal commandline I installed C# and F#. However, when I am trying to compile/run my code I get the following error:

```
open System;

public class Hello1
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
   }
} 

My Output:
sh: 0: Can't open undefined/build.sh
```

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUKgt.png

I tried to Google the answer, but I wasnt able to find it.
Do you have any idea what I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code does not include any tools to build C# or F#. It is just a text editor, like Sublime. It is not an IDE.

If you want to use Visual Studio Code to program for .NET in Linux, you need to decide if you want to use Mono or ASP.NET Core.

For ASP.NET Core you can find [instructions here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html) and check [this](https://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/) and [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/aspnet5) too.

For installing Mono, check [this page](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/).

Note that for F# you need to use something like [Ionide.io](http://ionide.io/).

As per today there are the following options if you really need an IDE:

1. [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/)
2. [Xamarin Studio](https://www.xamarin.com/studio) - a fork of MonoDevelop, supported by Xamarin
3. The newest and brightest addition - JetBrains' [Project Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/), which is planned for release later this year (Q4) but accessible for EAP right now

I personally think that Project Rider is the most promising tool, it has battle-tested products IdeaJ and Resharper under the bonnet and it is just a matter of time until it will become a de-facto the .NET IDE on Linux and Mac OS X. I would also prefer using it in Windows since it is *much* faster than Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi Alexey, your answer has been really useful. Would you recommend a IDE in particular to program F# and C# on Linux (since this VSC aint one)

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I am familiar with JetBrains stuff, so Project Rider would be great. I will start using MonoDevelop, as soon as the JetBrains program will be released Imma going to switch :)

Comment: I tried EAP of Rider and it really works but has some glitches. They send invites to everyone who subscribes, immediately.